# Как спарсить дату сайта?

Tags: python

Всех приветствую.

Парсю дату новостей с [этого портала](https://bnews.kz) .И после эти полученные даты преобразовываю в нужный мне формат с помощью библиотеки **dateparser** .

И произошла такая дилемма .У этого портала есть два типа дат. То есть вот так:[1 тип](https://bnews.kz/news/v_stolitse_zapushchena_novaya_programma_-akselerator_nur-sultana/) даты [2 тип](https://bnews.kz/news/nigmatulin-_deputaty_obespechat_effektivnuyu_zakonodatelnuyu_podderzhku_poslaniya_prezidenta/) даты.

[1 тип](https://bnews.kz/news/v_stolitse_zapushchena_novaya_programma_-akselerator_nur-sultana/) даты выглядит вот так и этот тип нормально преобразовывается с помощью библиотеки **dateparser** в нужный мне формат **2019-09-03 13:54:23**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[2 тип](https://bnews.kz/news/nigmatulin-_deputaty_obespechat_effektivnuyu_zakonodatelnuyu_podderzhku_poslaniya_prezidenta/) даты выглядит вот так и при попытке преобразования с помощью библиотеки **dateparser** результат **None**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думал [2 тип](https://bnews.kz/news/nigmatulin-_deputaty_obespechat_effektivnuyu_zakonodatelnuyu_podderzhku_poslaniya_prezidenta/) даты выводит None так как в библиотеке dateparser нужен год для преобразования в нужный мне формат.

Но я парсил на этом же портале новость 2016 года. И при попытке преобразовать дату в нужные мне формат результат был **None**

Вот участок кода который парсит даты:

> ```
> # < Собираем даты с страницы.
> def get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule):
>     if item_page is None:
>         return
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
>     item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
>     if item_datetime is not None:
>         item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
>         item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
>     else:
>         if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
>             item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]}).text
>             item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
>         else:
>             item_datetime = ''
>     return item_datetime
> ```

**Как решить эту проблему ?** **Как мне преобразовать преобразовать [2 тип](https://bnews.kz/news/nigmatulin-_deputaty_obespechat_effektivnuyu_zakonodatelnuyu_podderzhku_poslaniya_prezidenta/) даты?**

**UPD:** Создал переменную и присвоил ей значение в точь-точь как у 2 типа.И дал это `dateparser` библиотека нормально отработала.Думаю проблема в том что я парсю и еще ненужные `dateparser` элементы такие как пример: **2 Сентября,22:51 721** то есть **721** это цифра просмотров новости.

Вот место где я беру дату:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставил эту библиотеку, проверил различные комбинации дат с этого сайта. На всякий случай указал `languages=['ru']`, попробовал ваш `date_formats`. Во всех случаях выдает правильный `datetime`. Проверьте, правильно ли у вас `BeautifulSoup` находит сами такие даты.

Comment: @Jazzis,Я проверил BS4 он находит даты без проблем. Уточняющий вопрос,я правильно вас понял ? Вы использовали библиотеку `dateparser`?  И у вас даты по типу **2 Сентября, 13:33** преобразовывается нормально ?

Comment: Всё верно. У меня `Python 3.7.4` и `dateparser==0.7.1` (latest версия). Возможно у вас другая версия питона и библиотеки, и конкретно на них не работает? P. S. Комментарий написан без учета UPD.

Comment: @Jazzis,хм... Можете скинуть ваш код который работает ?  А на счет версий питона и библиотеки у меня все в порядке,я это в первую очередь проверил.P.S. Я думаю то что я указал в UPD и есть проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда вам надо над селекторами поработать, по которым ищите даты. Судя по коду вам надо брать первый `span` из `<div class="nl__details nl__details_left">`. Словами BS4 это будет что-то типа:

```
item_datetime = soup.select_one('div.nl__details.nl__details_left > span').text
dt = dateparser(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])

return dt
```

P. S. Насчет работоспособности не уверен, но судя по [документации](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `select_one` работает так.

Comment: Я думаю селекторы мне не подойдут.Так как правила выдергивания контента я беру из БД.И я думаю что лучше буду использовать другие методы.В любом случае благодарю вас за потраченное внимание и время)

Comment: @Jazzis, первый селектор внутри того `div` это ` > span`, угловая скобка говорит, что нужно строго искать вложенный тег. А без скобки будут искаться у всех детей, их детей и т.д.

Comment: Исправил ответ по замечанию @gil9red, спасибо :)